# How to add static text to the page layout?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Is there a way to add static text to Page Layout?  I need to provide instructional text on pages and can't see another way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in couple of ways.

1. Create a VF page with the static text and embed it on Page Layout
2. Define Field-Level Help (to add message to fields when user hovers on them) go to Your Name | Setup | Create | Objects click Edit next to field enter your text in Help Text field.

Comment: I just have insert like or in between two text fields is there anyway to achieve this.

Comment: As far as i know there is no way to inline edit/insert text in page layout. The simplest way would be embed VF page you can find instructions here http://blogs.developerforce.com/systems-integrator/2008/11/adding-a-visualforce-page-to-a-page-layout.html